# Django rest framework & external api

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i wanna get my data from an external API (https://example.com/consumers). Can I build my urls.py like this?

```
url(r'^(?P<test.com/consumers)>[0-9]+)$/', views.get, name="get"),
```

Or do you have any other(s) good idea(s) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it would be better to create your own url endpoint that maps to a view which makes a request to the external API.

```
# urls.py
url(r'^external-api/$', external_api_view)

# views.py
import requests
import time
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response

MAX_RETRIES = 5  # Arbitrary number of times we want to try

def external_api_view(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        attempt_num = 0  # keep track of how many times we've retried
        while attempt_num < MAX_RETRIES:
            r = requests.get("https://example.com/consumers", timeout=10)
            if r.status_code == 200:
                data = r.json()
                return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                attempt_num += 1
                # You can probably use a logger to log the error here
                time.sleep(5)  # Wait for 5 seconds before re-trying
        return Response({"error": "Request failed"}, status=r.status_code)
    else:
        return Response({"error": "Method not allowed"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Just an example. You can do it as a class-based view as well.

Comment: You should set timeout limit for external API call, or your view may block the other incoming requests for minutes.

Comment: Thanks @ToanNguyen for pointing that out, I added a timeout and included maximum number of retries

Comment: Thanks @ThomasJiang , i will try it like that, and after i'll implement the class-based view. 
Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are trying to achieve, this code will not work.

Firstly, `?P<name>` construct is just a way to give a symbolic name to a group. And it does not accept characters '.', '/' and ')'. So correct name would be something like `?P<consumer_id>`.

Secondly, even after you correct mistakes in the regular expression (like this, for example `r'^(?P<consumer_id>[0-9]+$)/'`), it will just match any URL like `YOURDOMAIN.COM/<integer_number>/`.

I suggest you learn [how regular expressions work in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) first.

Comment: where to give username and password to connect with the external API?