# How to call external API in django application with username and password

Tags: django

I am trying to receive data from an API endpoint in my django application. I found the solution here: [Django rest framework & external api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48435487/django-rest-framework-external-api).

But when I tried this solution I got error:

SSLError at /external-api
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='example.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /example (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))

When I open the external API directly on browser, I need to provide the username and password of the account which has access to that API. But while calling through API I am not providing it anywhere.

I am not sure how to set the username and password in the URL or in the settings file to access the external API.

Edited: Also I am not sure what could be the reason behind the error.

Comment: Are you really trying to connect to [example.com](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com)?

Comment: no the host and url are just changed in the question

Answer (score 0):

Then the certificate on the remote host failed verification (search the error message for a number of causes). If you think that's fine, then you can pass turn off verification:

```py
r = requests.get("https://example.com/consumers", timeout=10, verify=False)
```

Comment: With this getting output like: C:\Users\ric\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:1004: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning,
<Response [200]>

Comment: the print(r) not giving the data but instead giving <Response [200]>

Comment: can see the data with (r.text)

Comment: And if it's json, you can also use `r.json()`. The warning you can ignore, or put the real url here, so we can verify if the it is in your side or the host's side.

Answer (score 0):

- Try this

```
import requests 
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth 

response = requests.get('your-url', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('your-username', 'your-password')) 

print(response)
```

Comment: response = requests.get('your-url', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('your-username', 'your-password'), verify=False) this looks working with insecure warning